How to Solve the Issue between Google Drive sync and Windows Security ransomware protection feature?
New Windows has a feature called Ransomware Protection in Windows Settings >> Windows Security.
I use this feature to protect the folder of Google Drive.
However, it doesn't go well. At the first time the binary of Google Drive sync GoogleDriveFS.exe is accessing the folder, permission is given to it manually.
But after Google Drive update, the block by Windows Security is shown again. I guess that is because the path to GoogleDriveFS.exe is inside a folder with version name which is changing at every Google Drive update:
C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\92.0.0.0\GoogleDriveFS.exe

How to solve this path containing version number problem?

Ransomware Protection has been around for 10+ years. What version of Windows are you run exactly? Have you created an exclusion rule for the directory within Windows Defender? Create an exclusion for C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream and you won’t have to worry about the child directory changing

Controlled Folder Access is working as intended and isn't the root of the problem, the way Google's Drive team has programmed the Drive installer is since it outputs every update into its own version folder instead of the normal, sane way of not doing that (there are other developers who attach versioning to an executable name, creating the same problem). The only solution is to add the new GoogleDriveFS.exe path as allowed within Controlled Folder Access (there may be a way via cli to add a wildcard path, but I can't recall for sure - e.g. ..\Drive File Stream\*\GoogleDriveFS.exe)

(Cont'd...) Try the following in PowerShell: Add-MpPreference -ControlledFolderAccessAllowedApplications "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\*\GoogleDriveFS.exe"

@JW0914 that looks like an answer

@JW0914 - I will trust but verify that statement.

Please try following powershell function:
function Get-GoogleDriveFSPath {
try {
    $installLocation = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{6BBAE539-2232-434A-A4E5-9A33560C6283}" -Name "InstallLocation"
    if (Test-Path "$installLocation") {
        Show-Notification -message "$installLocation"
        return "$installLocation"
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host "Google Drive install location not found in registry. Trying file system..."
}
return $null}

You should call in main code.
For example;
$gdfsPath=Get-GoogleDriveFSPath


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
